# Nested loop unrolling

Tags: c++, templates

Given I have a function

```
double doSomething(int const a, int const b, int const c) { /*...*/}
```

and I would like to test this function for different inputs a,b and c. Then, I could give a list with possible parameters and test all combinations with three loops:

```
int aTest[] = {1,2,3,4}
int bTest[] = {-5,-3,0}
int cTest[] = {2,65,8,0,-100}
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        for (unsinged int k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {
            double val = doSomething(aTest[i], bTest[j], cTest[k]);
            //Compare results etc.
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler will hopefully be smart enough to unroll these loops at compile time, so that something like this is generated:

```
doSomething(1,-5,2);
doSomething(1,-5,65);
doSomething(1,-5,8);
//...
```

However, given my compiler is not smart enough to do the unrolling, how would I do with templates?

Comment: Did you try turning on optimizations using the `-O2` flag while compiling?

Comment: How are you saying that compiler is not doing the unrolling? Using `-O3` will result in very strict unrolling by the compiler.

Comment: While I like the provided answer and it precisely addresses the question, I wish we were past this era of reaching for recursive metaprogramming just to force the compiler to unroll basic loops with a small number of iterations defined as literal constants. We should be past that stage now where we need to reach for such powerful tools to solve something any reasonable optimizer can handle with far more straightforward code. This stuff was cool in the 90s -- now we should be a little more hesitant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do something like this:

```
double TestData[] = { 1.5, 2.7, 3.6, 4.5, 7.9 };

template<int K>
class Super {
public:
    inline static void Do()
    {
        Super<K - 1>::Do();
        double val = doSomething( TestData[K] );
    }
};

template<>
class Super<0> {
public:
    inline static void Do()
    {
        double val = doSomething( TestData[0] );
    }
};
```